# show posts based similar category as the page category in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show posts, that are in a similar category as the page. Here is my code (just the important php part, not html)? What is wrong?

```
<?php $pages = get_pages(array('child_of' => 13)); ?> 
    <?php foreach ($pages as $page): ?>
        <?php echo $page->post_title; ?>
        <?php echo $page->post_excerpt; ?>
        <?php echo $page->post_content; ?>
            <?php $categories = get_the_category($page->ID);?>
                <?php query_posts('post_type=projekt&category_name=$categories&showposts=1');?>
                    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 
                        <?php the_title(); ?></a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Thanx!

Comment: Didn't you forget an `endwhile;`?

Comment: endwhile; helped (no error), but the post don't show up :(

Comment: I didn't say it's THE solution, I pointed an error :)

Comment: Allright it helped to clean my code! Thnx

Answer (score 2):

try

```
<?php $pages = get_pages(array('child_of' => 13)); 
foreach ($pages as $page) {
    echo $page->post_title;
    echo $page->post_excerpt;
    echo $page->post_content;
    $categories = get_the_category($page->ID);
    query_posts('post_type=projekt&category_name='.$categories.'&showposts=1');
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <a><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php endwhile;
endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

without testing, this line looks incorrect:

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=projekt&category_name=$categories&showposts=1');?>
```

the `$categories` variable is being interpreted literally because of the single quotes

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=projekt&category_name=' . $categories . '&showposts=1');?>
```

Comment: anyway i repaired my code following your instruction, that looks better. Thanx

Comment: Other problem, all the post in similar category than the last page.

Comment: not sure what you mean, might be best creating a new question if you can't solve it though

Comment: There are multiple pages, not just one in the query, and i want to show the posts in the same category for every page. (Sorry i was not clear). But is shows just the last page category everywhere..

Comment: from the wordpress docs, selecting multiple categories is done by `query_posts('cat=8,4,3');`

Comment: I want to do it dynamical, dont pre-specify the categories.

Comment: hmm, only thing I can think of right now is having the similar categories have a parent category so you could dynamically use the parent? I'm not a wordpress expert though.

Comment: The related posts and pages is in the same category. I want to "list" the page and the post, which is in the same category.